# Another probability combinatorics problem inspired by Bible

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I asked [a probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438565/a-probability-problem-similar-to-birthday-problem-inspired-by-bible) inspired by Bible.

Continuing this topic, consider another question related to this. (My intuition strongly suspects that it's false (I mean nearly zero probability.), but I ask to be sure.)

Suppose all humans are descendants of Adam and Eve. Suppose that all chromosomes of Adam and Eve were distinct. So there is total $2\times23 = 46$ chromosomes of humandkind.

A person has $2\times23$ chromosomes and so there are 70368744177664 "variants of a person".

Noah had three sons. Every son of Noah had a wife.

Suppose that each of the wives of Noah's sons got one of these variants completely randomly, suppose the same for Noah himself and his wife, and suppose that the Noah sons get the combination of chromosomes from Noah and his wife randomly (limited by the fact that their chromosomes are of fixed parents).

Please help me to calculate the probability that all $2\times46 = 92$ chromosomes were present in the survivors of the Flood (including or excluding Noah himself and his wife, as I am not sure if they were too old to have more children).

You may believe Bible or not, but this is a valid mathematical wordproblem.

Comment: "You may believe Bible or not" So kind of you.

Comment: Don't people have 23 _pairs_ of chromosomes?  So Adam has 46, Eve has 46, and their son Cain gets one chromosome 1 from Adam, one from Eve, etc.  This gives 4 possible arrangements in each of the 23 spots, leading to the $7\times 10^{13}$ 'variants'.

Comment: @Titus This was already considered in comments to my first question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438565/a-probability-problem-similar-to-birthday-problem-inspired-by-bible

Comment: I just wanted to stress that there would not be 46 chromosomes in all of humankind according to the story; there would be 92.

Comment: @Titus Thanks, this was my error, I've edited the question

Comment: You seem to assume that there is a binary choice for each chromosome.  But in fact there are many genes on each chromosome.  Your value  of $2^{46}$ is far to small. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I am not a biologist, but as far as I know, individual genes in a chromosome are always present together. In other words, a chromosome is never split in lesser parts (such as genes). So your point is not valid

Comment: @Titus : In fact, a person gets various parts of each chromosome from the father and various parts from the mother.  One does not get a whole chromosome from just one parent. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @porton : You seem quite uninformed.  See this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover

Comment: @MichaelHardy It seems that I have forgotten school biology. You are right (accordingly what I've read on the Web after your note), parts of chromosomes recombine (however this happens in egg and sperms cell when they are formed, not when they "merge"). This renders my entire idea completely wrong. However, a mathematical wordproblem remains valid

Answer (score 0):

Write $C_i = \{ a_i, A_i, e_i, E_i\}$ for the 4 original chromosome $i$'s present in Adam and Eve.  Let Noah's chromosomal makeup be $N = (n_1, N_1,\dots, N_{23})$, a 46-vector in $\Omega = C_1 \times C_1 \times \dots \times C_{23}\times C_{23}$.  To simplify things, we know that Noah's sons aren't going to bring any new chromosomes to the table so let's start by answering "what's the probability that all of $C_1$ can be found in Noah, his wife, or the three brothers' wives, assuming they draw their chromosomes at random from the original pool."

Since each person in question gets two 1-chromosomes, we have 10 draws from the set $\{a_1,A_1,e_1,E_1\}$ and, since the draws are independent, elementary probability gives that
$$ P(\textrm{some chromosome in } C_1 \textrm{ is missing from the survivors}) = {3^{10} \over 2^{18}} \approx {9 \over 40}. $$
Then it follows that (each chromosome being independent of the others),
$$ P(\textrm{some chromosome in } \cup_1^{23} C_i \textrm{ is missing }) \approx  1 - \left({31 \over 40} \right)^{23} \approx 0.997.$$
That is, given the assumptions (enough generations have gone by that the draws from $C_i$ are nearly independent; a grossly oversimplified model of reproduction and mutation; etc.) the absence of a chromosome is almost certain.

That being said, events far less probable occur regularly throughout the Bible, so I wouldn't look at this as anything more than entertainment.  Calculations like this are just as likely to reaffirm faith as to vindicate doubt.